# select not null values among multiple rows across Multiple columns in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, duplicates, notnull

Is there a way to select not null values across multiple fields from a set of duplicates and return as a single row.  For example, if we have a sample data set like below

Data set

[image]

As you can see in the simplified oracle sql data set above, for each email address there are multiple records with null values for sign_up_page, last_sign_up_page, supplimental_data,last_sign_up_timestamp, last_sign_up_widget. but all these column data will have only one not null value for a specific email address.

Is it possible to retrieve a single record for each email_address(grouping email address) by selecting the not null values of the respective column data. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.  desired sample output data set example image: 
[image]

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select email_address, first_name,
       max(sign_up_page) as sign_up_page,
       max(last_sign_up_page) as last_sign_up_page,
       . . .
from t
group by email_address, first_name;
```

Note:  This will condense all values down to a single row per `email_address`/`first_name`.  If there are duplicates, only one is kept.